# Android Studio - Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Foo:dexDebug' - but why?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-studio

I receive this error :

```
Gradle: Execution failed for task ':Foo:dexDebug'.
```

And since 2day ! I have try a lot of solution... But nothing work fine ! Really ! Need Help !
I work with android Studio. (IntelliJ IDEA)

For this following three directory

```
   FooProject [RootProject]
   |-gradle
   |-libraries
     |-facebook [library1]
       |-libs
          |-android-support-v4.jar
       |-res
          |-*.(drawable...)
       |-src
          |-*.java
       |-build.gradle
       |-AnroidManifest.xml
       |-facebook.iml
     |-foosdk [library2]
       |-res
          |-*.(drawable...)
       |-src
          |-*.java
       |-libs
          |-YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
       |-build.gradle
       |-AnroidManifest.xml
       |-foosdk.iml
   |-Foo [project for execution]
     |-libs
        |-commons-io-1.3.2.jar
        |-commons-lang3-3.1.jar
        |-jackson-core-asl-1.9.11.jar
        |-jackson-databind-2.1.4.jar
        |-jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.11.jar
        |-robospice-1.4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
        |-robospice-cache-1.4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
        |-robospice-spring-android-1.4.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
        |-spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
        |-spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar
        |-YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar
     |-src
      |-main
        |-java
          |-*.java
        |-res
          |-*.(drawable...)
     |-build.gradle
     |-AnroidManifest.xml
     |-Foo.iml
   |-gradlew
   |-gradlew.bat
   |-local.properties
   |-settings.gradle
   |-RootProject.iml
```

I have for my settings.gradle

```
include ':libraries:facebook', :libraries:foosdk', ':foo'
```

For the files "build.gradle" :

**For libraries/facebook/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

**For libraries/foosdk/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

**For Foo/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'

    compile project(':libraries:foosdk')
    compile project(':libraries:facebook')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}



android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No... Never... You have the same problem ?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem? or a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Foo project in /Foo or /foo folder (note the upper case)? You may need to correct the include 'foo' to 'Foo'?

If that doesn't work, please paste the info or debug output of your Gradle build. If you're running AndroidStudio and don't have any output, go to the root of your project and run `gradlew.bat assembleDebug --info` (on Wins) or `./gradlew assembleDebug --info` (on Linux/Mac) or `--debug` and paste the output here so we can see what went wrong exactly.

Comment: I read this just now... And I haven't any trace :/ Sorry, and thanks